# CakePHP 3.2 find first with where

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP 3.2. Here is my find query:

```
  $a=$this->A->find('all', ['where' => [ 'b=='=>5, 'c>'=>1000 ]])->first();   

  // For debuging what I receive:
  $data=$a->toArray();
  print_r($data);
```

I'd like to select first record in 'A', whose column 'b' equals 5 and column 'c' is grater than 1000. What am I doing incorrectly? The above query returns all records from 'A' table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `conditions` instead of `where`

```
$a=$this->A->find('all', ['conditions' => ['b'=>5, 'c >'=>1000]])->first();
```

Comment: It works indeed. Could you please explain me why my 'where' did not work. I have never used 'conditions' before. What is the difference?

Comment: Because that's the official syntax. See "The list of options supported by find()" at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data

Comment: Thank you! I migrated from cake 1.3 to 3.2 and it has changed

Comment: `find all cars with name prefix 'A' but take only the first one` vs `find first car with name prefix 'A'`...looool

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
$a = $this->A->find()
    ->where([ 'b' => 5, 'c >' => 1000 ])
    ->first();   

debug($a)
```

you don't need to call toArray() since first already returns a single entity

Comment: toArray is to debuging needs only. Your code is not working: Call to a member function find() on boolean

Comment: of course you can convert the entity to an array but for debugging purposes it gives more or less the same information so I consider it not very usefull. Also the code is correct (as long as you actually have a Model named A).

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this: 
    $data = $this->A->find()->where(['b' => 5, 'c >' => 1000])->first();

Answer (score 0):

Use **conditions** instead of where

```
$query = $articles->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Articles.title LIKE' => '%Ovens%']
]);
$result = $query->toArray();
```